# Get images from a database into content also from a database

Tags: php, database, image

Horrible title but I've got no idea how to describe it in a different way :3

Basically for our school project we have to get all our page content from the database. So I've entered the content into the database and created a function to paste it onto my page. The problem I'm having is that I also get some of the images from a different table.

My page is entered using

```
<?php echo $row['page_content']; ?>
```

So for the images I used to do something like this is within the page:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-height">
    <a href="portfolio-item">
        <img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="<?php echo getImage(6); ?>" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Obviously the echo within a echo isn't going to work but I've got no clue how to work around this. Its not like I can simply outspace it like you can do in smaller pieces of text, for example:

```
echo "test text". $row['image'] . "moretext";
```

Is there a way to do this, or do i simply have to input the direct links to the images. I mean the page content is in the database anyway but I prefer having them in a seperate table

EDIT: 
These are the functions I'm using to get the content and the images:

```
function getContents(){
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);

    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }else{
        $page = 1;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_ID = :page";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(':page', $page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetch();
    return $row;
}

function getImage($image){
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_ID = :image";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(':image', $image, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetch();
    return $row['image_url'];
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the function body of getImage(integer)?

Comment: have u succeded to display images

Comment: Is the div you posted the assigned value of $row['page_content']?

Comment: @TimvanderLippe no the actual content is like the full html of the webpage, the div I posted is just a example of how my images are added to the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to somehow mark images in page text with special syntax and then process it before output. For example you could insert `{{ing:n}}` into content to be later replace with link to n-th image. Let's say you chose syntax `<?php echo getImage(n); ?>` :) (which you absolutely shouldn't).

Then content passed through function like the following should contain images links:

```
function insertImages($content)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/<\?php echo getImage\(([0-9]+)\); \?>/', function($match) {
        return getImage($match[1]);
   }, $content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks allot :) What would be the correct way to paste images if the way I do it is wrong?

Comment: @Crecket I don't think there is any single correct way. Usually when I store html in database is when the content is edited with editor by site user (manager) rather then developer and in this case I use some markup language, some of which offer own syntax for attached images.